# Docker containers communicating on the same network with React and Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 containers running on the same network (React app and Spring boot app), i want to deploy the application with docker compose on a common machine, therefore I want to:

1. Override the api url on the react app to send the request to url backend
2. Override the frontend url on the backend in order to enable CORS configuration

Docker Compose file:

```
services:
  my-client:
    container_name: my-client
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./my-client
      args:
        REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL: http://my-service:8080
    depends_on:
      - my-service
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./my-client:/app
    networks:
      - my-network

  my-service:
    image: 'my-service'
    container_name: my-service
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
       - postgres
       - mongodb
    environment:
      - CLIENT_URL=http://my-client:3000
    networks:
      - my-network
  networks:
    my-network: 
      driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile frontend:

```
FROM node:14.14.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
ARG REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL
ENV REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=${REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Api url variable in frontend:

```
export const serverUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL;
```

On backend I am using the variable in application.yml like and define the CORS config:

```
client:
  url: ${CLIENT_URL}
```

I am expecting to run docker-compose and make the frontend communicate with backend, but the frontend is sending the request to
`Request URL: http://my-service:8080/api/auth/login`
Error: (failed)net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED   preflight xhr

What is the best approach in making this work? Any suggestion to make this implementation better, best practices?

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't find any issue in this, the request URL seems correct as per your docker-compose configuration. Please mention it clearly that what problem you are facing and what's your expectation with it?

Comment: Your React application is running in the end user's browser.  It is _not_ running in a container, even if you have a container serving it.  The browser knows nothing about the Docker networking and can't use the Docker-network hostnames.  You need to connect to the server's host name and a published `ports:` number.

Answer (score -1):

You missed to open port from Dockerfile. U can open port using keyword 'EXPOSE' write 'EXPOSE 3000' to your Dockerfile and same to your backend Dockerfile otherwise it won't work? I think this cannot help u to solve all problems. maybe )

Comment: "Expose" as a Docker verb does close to nothing; adding (or removing) a Dockerfile `EXPOSE` directive will have no impact on networking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).